# Is it possible to prevent linebreak after H2 tags?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to display something on the same line but keep the H2 tag (just so I don't have to change it in a bunch of different places).  Can this be done using CSS?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding the CSS `h2 { display: inline }`.

Comment: @fredley: The longest two seconds *of your life!*

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
h2 {
  display:inline;
}
```